Has the cryptocurrencies industry become the 2nd largest election-related corporate donor in the US, after the oil industry?
A NYT opinion piece:

It is an astounding outlay, enough cash in a single election cycle to make crypto corporations the second-largest contributor in total election-related spending in the 14 years since Citizens United. Only the fossil-fuel industry has spent more since 2010 [...]

Axios even has a graph:



I'm skeptical that the shaded bar described as "crypto sector corps" are in fact what it's claimed to be, by and large. The first piece links to a piece in The New Yorker that sounds a lot less definitive also talking about Airbnb etc., in the same piece which I would not exactly call a "crypto sector corp".

The mention of Airbnb in the New Yorker article is part of a profile of Chris Lehane, who worked with them on specific campaigns around 2016; the connection is that he now heads a "super PAC" called Fairshake, which is specifically funded by the cryptocurrency industry to promote their interests. It is the amount recently raised or spent by that specific organisation that is the subject of the claim in all these articles.

$250m total donations for 2024 seems very low to me, total campaign spending is in the double-digit billions. Is that due to the restriction to coorperate donors and the vast majority of politicial donations come from individuals?

@quarague: yeah, I was able to confirm the raw amounts claimed (for crypto companies), but that's only part of an answer.

@quarague: AFAICT Musk donated a pretty similar sum https://youtu.be/KmQLhtlHO1o?t=418 ($118m) but I guess he personally isn't counted as an "industry".

The claim seems be based on something like this:

Of the $160 million in total contributions Fairshake has raised since it was founded, around $155 million — or 94% — can be traced back to just four companies: Ripple, Andreesen Horowitz, Coinbase and Jump Crypto.

Three of these are clearly pretty focused on crypto-related stuff. The last two I didn't bother investigate in any detail simply due to their name. Ripple is involved in a (pretty big, money wise) regulatory/lawsuit tussle with the SEC over digital tokens, so related enough.
The more difficult Q seems to be how much is Andreessen Horowitz (AH) paying into that, as they are a more diversified venture capitalist. (If Wikipedia is up-to-date on this, the two labelled-as-such crypto funds AH runs amount to around $800m out of AH's $42b capitalization.)
Thanks to IMSoP for pointing this out, in the Public Citizen report, which uses just 2024 as the time period, AH put in a relatively paltry sum of $1.75m, whereas Coinbase and Ripple about $50m each. And Jump Crypto $15m.

The Public Citizen report given as a source in the Axios article breaks down the numbers in a couple of ways. A couple of clicks from there gets you to the FEC filings which would be the most definitive source.

@IMSoP: Interesting. According to that AH put in a relatively paltry sum of $1.75m, whereas Coinbase and Ripple about $50m each. And Jump Crypto $15m.
